# Need help understanding how to format inline CSS of Table data from a JS file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a javascript file that someone wrote for me that updates the form data that a user selects then displays the radio buttons and appropriate costs.

The inline CSS from this script seems to work fine in Chrome and Firefox, but fails in Safari, Internet Explorer and Opera.

I do not understand why it does this does not work or how to fix it so that it is solid in all browsers.

Thanks in advance.

```
function update(sqin,name) {
    $('#display_size').html(name);
    str9 ="<table  style='margin-left:10px;float:left;'>";
    for (index = 0; index < prices[sqin].length; index++) {
        var qty = prices[sqin][index][0];
        str9 += '<tr><td style="padding-top:5px;width:90px;"><input type="radio" id="radio_btn" name="productpr1" VALUE="'+qty+':'+prices[sqin][index][1]+
        '<label for="radio_btn"><span style="font-family: \'Open Sans\', serif;font-size: 20px;">'+qty+'</span></label>'+
    '</td><td style="font-family: \'Open Sans\', serif;font-size: 20px; padding-top:5px;">$'+prices[sqin][index][1]+'</td></tr>';

        if (index == 4) {
            str9 += "</table><table style='margin-left:175px;'>";
        }

    }
    str9 += "</table>";
    $('#price_table').html(str9);

    $('[name="product1[]"]').val("ea "+name+" Die-Cut Decals");
```

[image]

Comment: Remove inline styles and use classes in the first place. This will make it a lot easier to debug. Then a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/) example would be awesome… ;-) (edit: from the looks of your image I'd say that IE doesn't use the same font?)

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have a clue how to remove the inline styles and add classes, nor how to use the jsBin.  Sorry.  :(   I do notice that the font looks different in IE, no clue why tho.

Comment: Is there somewhere I might find an example of a CSS classes for the table data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9QTHw/) will give you a start.

CSS

```
table {
    width: 300px;
}
span {
    color: red;
}
table tr:first-child td {
    background-color: #c0bdbd;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
table td {
    padding-left: 30px;
}
table tr:last-child td {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
```

### }

Edit:
There are a variety of approaches you can take in this situation:

1. You can do what your colleague did and put EVERYTHING in javascript - HTML, CSS, javascript - and display it on the screen.
2. You can put the HTML in the javascript, and style the output with "fixed" CSS in `<style></style>` section in your header, or in an attached CSS file.
3. You can put the HTML "fixed" on the page, with CSS styling in the header or a CSS file, and then use the javascript to ONLY place the data into the structure you build with HTML/CSS. That is what I have done above.

How would you choose among the three above depends on your application and your personal preference. I try to avoid doing inline CSS styling with javascript because the code looks so complex and is often difficult to follow - particularly if you are not the one who wrote it. I looked at the code in your question, saw all the inline styling - and got a headache :-).

It's much easier, when possible, to separately build the house framework (HTML), add colors, decoration, furniture, design (CSS), then do home automation (javascript).

Comment: Thanks for that, but where would I implement this into the javascript or do I put this in a separate file? Not sure how, I experimented with putting it into the code above, but it failed.

Comment: This is a big project - moving from javascript to HTML/CSS/JavaScript. I've made this fiddle to be partially responsive to your question - http://jsfiddle.net/V3scg/. Note that all of the inline styling has been moved to CSS.

Comment: After thinking a bit, a different approach, and perhaps more efficient, would be for you to "play" with the inline styling and the HTML support structure that you have, to make the table "fit" in IE. Just multiple experiments.

Comment: Thanks Tim for your great help, I agree that having the inline CSS is exceptionally confusing.  It would be nice to have more efficient neater code, but it is a lot for me to understand since my skills are weak at best.  I was able to manipulate the code and it seems to work across all browsers. I changed this code: if (index == 4) {
            str9 += "</table><table style='margin-left:175px;'>";
        } to this: if (index == 4) {
    str9 += "</table><table  style='margin-left:10px;float:left;'>";
   }

Comment: Excellent! Congratulations! Sometimes in "little" things like this is's better to do something "inelegant" - changing the size of a div or even removing a 1px thick border can make things "shape up". Best of luck.